# How to create a MySQL trigger to keep track of changes

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I have a table called "products", the following columns are an example of what can be found in this table (although there are many more):

- products_id
- price
- our_cost

When price/our_cost is updated, I want to insert a row into a products_history table with the following:

- products_id being changed
- field being changed
- old value
- new value
- employee id of the employee making the change (available to me as the variable $login_id in PHP)

Here's my current trigger, and while I expect this to work (except entering the employee_id) I get an error saying `Column count doesn't match value at row 1`

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER after_update_products
    AFTER UPDATE ON products FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET @History = '';

        IF NEW.price <> OLD.price THEN
            SET @History = CONCAT(@History, '(', OLD.products_id, ", price, ", OLD.price, ", ", NEW.price, "),");
        END IF;

        IF NEW.our_cost <> OLD.our_cost THEN
            SET @History = CONCAT(@History, '(', OLD.products_id, ", our_cost, ", OLD.our_cost, ", ", NEW.our_cost, "),");
        END IF;

        IF @History <> '' THEN
            SET @History = SUBSTRING(@History, 2, CHAR_LENGTH(@History) - 3);
            INSERT INTO products_history (products_id, field, old_value, new_value) VALUES (@History);
        END IF;
    END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

What am I doing wrong?

On top of that, do I need to worry about putting quotes around the things I'm inserting (when I do this the error above still remains), and will escaping be an issue?

Also, how can I get PHP to add the $login_id to each row that was updated?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the '(' and ')' from around @History.

```
INSERT INTO products_history (products_id, field, old_value, new_value) VALUES @History;
```

Also, you wont be able to have the PHP script pass the login_id to the Trigger, as that's handled beyond PHP's influence. You might not be able to use TRIGGER, and might have to build that INSERT statement in your PHP script.

Comment: I've tried that, and adjusted my SUBSTRING accordingly, but then I get the following error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@History; END IF; END'`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating an extra variable? You don't really need it. Why don't you try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_update_products
AFTER UPDATE ON products FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.price <> OLD.price THEN
        INSERT INTO products_history (products_id, field, old_value, new_value) VALUES (old.products_id,'price',old.price,new.price);
    END IF;

    IF NEW.our_cost <> OLD.our_cost THEN
        INSERT INTO products_history (products_id, field, old_value, new_value) VALUES (old.products_id,'our_cost',old.our_cost,new.our_cost);
    END IF;
END;
```

I'm not very clear about your last question "Also, how can I get PHP to add the $login_id to each row that was updated?"

Comment: Because if a lot of changes are made at once, one query should be faster.

As for the $login_id. When a change is added to the history, there is a column for employee_id, I need the trigger to insert the $login_id in the employee_id field.

Comment: Well maybe as Brian says you'll need to handle it all from PHP. You can biuld a function or a stored procedure and you just call it from PHP and send the parameters

Comment: That's what I'm already doing, but there are hundreds of pages on my website that make changes to this table, I was hoping to handle it all in one place rather than having to make a function call from every page that updates this table.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple add a "employee_id" field to your product list, then, the trigger should like something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_update_products
AFTER UPDATE ON products FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.price <> OLD.price THEN
        INSERT INTO products_history (products_id, field, old_value, new_value, guy, date) VALUES (old.products_id,'price',old.price,new.price,new.employe_id,now());
    END IF;

    IF NEW.our_cost <> OLD.our_cost THEN
        INSERT INTO products_history (products_id, field, old_value, new_value, guy, date) VALUES (old.products_id,'our_cost',old.our_cost,new.our_cost,new.employe_id,now());
    END IF;
END;
```